# Installing Ubuntu Studio aside Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I was just wondering if I could install Ubuntu Studio without getting rid of Ubuntu 13.04? I'm not looking to dual boot, just want to see if its possible to install Studio on top of 13.04.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think as long as you have an empty harddrive, or partition, you shouldn't have any problem.  You'll have dual boot, Ubuntu, and Ubuntu Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Studio, as it name describes, is a Ubuntu version but focused to the multimedia purposes. To do that task, it uses a Real Time (kind of Low Latency) Linux kernel.

The main differences between this kernel and the usual is that uses **less time to response** to a multimedia actions (in music is crucial to play and listen the sound that you are making in less than 10ms), but the **overall performance is worse** than the generic kernel (here an example: http://sevencapitalsins.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/low-latency-kernel-wtf)

Then, if you want Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio, both in the same SO (you don't want dual boot), you can install one OS (Ubuntu for example) and install all the packages of the other flavour over it like this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video
```

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu

As a conclusion, you could have both operative systems installed as a one OS but you are able to work only with one kernel, the generic or the low-latency one (depending if you need performance or multimedia purposes), and you need to reboot when you want to change to the other (the same scene as if you have a dual boot system).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just want the applications and the settings that Ubuntu Studio comes with, and not the desktop.
In that case do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency ubuntustudio-audio
```

If you want other than audio applications, just install those too. You can find all of them by doing:

```
apt-cache search ubuntustudio
```

Finally, you'll want to make sure the user is in audio group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
```

..and that audio group is handed realtime privilege. Make sure the file:

```
/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf
```

is not named:

```
/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf.disabled
```

If it is, rename it. Reboot, enjoy!